# How to show the function $f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)\sin(1/(x^2+y^2)^{1/2})$ is differentiable everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

How to show that the function:
 $$f(x,y)= \begin{cases} (x^2+y^2)\sin\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}}& (x,y)\neq(0,0) \\
         0& (x,y)= (0,0)
 \end{cases}$$
 is differentiable everywhere?

I have been trying to prove it with the definition of differentiability but don't know how cancel out the $x^2$ and $y^2$.

Comment: f(x,y)=0 when (x,y)=(0,0) just to be clear

Comment: Please use $ before and after an equation.

Comment: Remark: the function you describe is $f(v)=\|v\|^2sin(1/\|v\|)$. Where the norm is the Euclidian norm on $R^2$ (for $v\not =0$)

Comment: @Surb That still doesn't necessarily make the function differentiable at the origin...

Comment: @DonAntonio Indeed, I mixed up...

Comment: It is worth knowing that this is an example of differentiable function with discontinuous partial derivatives: http://mathinsight.org/differentiable_function_discontinuous_partial_derivatives

Comment: For the same reason, @Jack, that $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$ is differentiable everywhere but its derivative is discontinuous at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the partial derivatives exist and are continuous at any point $\;(x,y)\neq(0,0)\;$ and thus the function's differentiable there. At the origin the partial derivatives **also** exist and equal zero, yet they aren't continuous, so we go by the definition:

$$\frac{f(y,k)-f(0,0)-f'_x(0,0)-f'_y(0,0)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=\frac{\left(h^2+k^2\right)\sin\frac1{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=$$

$$=\sqrt{h^2+k^2}\sin\frac1{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\xrightarrow[(h,k)\to(0,0)]{}0$$

and thus...

Comment: @Jack, I was being stupid there. After a day, I should delete all my comments.

Comment: @Lubin Done...and thanks anyway. (Shall delete this later, too...)